# Using MySQLi to connect

Tags: php, mysql

I've just updated to PHP 5.6, and several things are depreciated from 5.3 which I had been using. I know this is simple, but I suppose I want to think it through out loud, and request suggestions for making it better.

My old code looked something like this:

```
 <?php 
         
         include('req.php');
         include('bank.php');
         
     $query="SELECT * FROM xx WHERE xx IN ('xx')";
        
          $resource=mysql_query($query,$link);
          echo "
        <table id=\"space\" class=\"sortable\" align=\"center\" border=\"0\" width=\"95%\">
        <tr>
        <td><b>Column 1</b></td><td><b>Column 2</b></td><td><b>Column 3</b></td><td><b>Column 4</b></td><td><b>Column 5</b></td><td><b>Column 6</b></td><td><b>Column 3</b></td></tr> ";
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($resource))
    { 
    echo "<tr><td>".$result[1]."  </td><td>".$result[8]."</td><td>".$result[15]."</td><td>".$result[21]."</td><td>".$result[17]."</td><td>".$result[16]."</td><td><a href='/pages/things.php?result=$result[24]'>Link</a></td></tr>";
    } echo "</table>";
     ?></p>
```

Where bank.php looks like this:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die                      ('Error connecting to mysql');
mysql_select_db($dbname);
?>
```

and req.php looks something like this:

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'db.server.com';
$dbuser = 'xx';
$dbpass = 'xx';
$dbname = 'xx';
?>
```

I think the right answer is to change bank.php to this:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die                      ('Error connecting to mysql');
mysqli_database($dbname);
?>
```

But I'm not sure how to phrase the query.  Can anyone help here?  Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You updated to PHP 5.6? This version hasn't been supported in years

Comment: All support for PHP5.6 ended over two years ago. You should upgrade to PHP 8.

Comment: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-connect.php

Comment: I gave you two links. Read my answers in both of them, however, I would not recommend using mysqli. If you are up for it, consider changing to PDO, which is simpler to use than mysqli